# Cronjob wget only posting the first variable

Tags: php, cron, wget

I have a php script that is run via cron every minute that is simply writing the request URI to a txt file, but it is only posting the first variable in the url.

If I access the url via a browser :

```
https://example.com/test.php?k=1234&v=5678
```

I get the expected results in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` :

```
/test.php?k=1234&v=5678
```

But when run as a cronjob with `wget` :

```
* * * * * wget -q https://example.com/test.php?k=1234&v=5678 >/dev/null 2>&1
```

This is the output of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` :

```
/test.php?k=1234
```

Is `wget` only capable of posting one variable in a url or is there something else I'm missing here?

Comment: Just put the entire url in double quotes, or single ones, as may work here.

Comment: Your ampersand is being interpreted as 'run this in the background` operator.

Comment: Run that wget command from the cli as-is and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks bro! Thought it would be something obvious that I was missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the entire url in double quotes, or single ones, as may work here.